# Extract Twitter using RapidMiner - Going beyond the limited "Search Twitter" Operator

Tags: twitter, rapidminer

I already have an account in Twitter Dev, which allowed me to get a Consumer Key and secret, which I used to generate my token. Now I am trying to send token in request for Twitter API by using the operators "Get Page", "Jason to XML" and "Write Document". However, I do not know which URL to write in the "Get Page" operator. Is it Request token URL Authorize URL or Access token URL ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

In general the request URL contains the [REST API call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_services), while you are providing your authorization credentials e.g. via request properties in the HTTP header, OAuth mechanisms and the like. An REST API call is build up on a base URL awaiting a call, in case of twitter `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json`, combined with a state and HTTP options forming your request. If your searching for tweets from a given user account (like @twitterapi) your request URL part would look like `q=%40twitterapi`. Here a key `q` is given with the value `%40twitterapi`, where %40 is a representation of the '@' symbol.

Providing key-value-pairs via GET using the HTTP protocol is initialized with a leading '?'. Hence your REST request would look like this: 
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi`. This example is taken from the [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

That's about the URL.

For the RapidMiner site, I'd try to use the *Enrich Data by Webservice* operator. You can fill in the *url* parameter with your request URL and set the HTTP header for using an authentication token using the *request properties* parameter. As a *property* use `Authorization` and for the *value* you use a string starting with `Bearer` followed by your token. So a potential *value* could be `Bearer 943582034-IH3k6hlskfdj32l4hks`.

You can choose betweent different *query types* (e.g., String Matching, Regular Expression and others) to define the handling of the received payload given as an response to your request.

Before playing around with the operator, you can try using a tool like Postman (Chrome Plugin) or HTTPrequester (Firefox Add-on) to work directly with the HTTP GET request and its response.

Sorry for not including more references, but Stackoverflow doesn't allow for more than two if your reputation is below 10...

Comment: NOTE: Just to save you time - After playing around for hours trying to get this done, I figured out that the RM 7.6.001 Version seems not to send the request properties properly. Therefore the authentication is not recognized and mos properly no data returned. Details can be seen here: https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/RapidMiner-Studio-Forum/BUG-Enrich-Data-by-Webservice-Web-Mining-Does-not-pass-request/m-p/44049#M29167 . But I might also be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with the above - use the Enrich Data via Webservice operator.  You'll need to download the [Web Mining extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_web) in order to see it.  If you re-post on the [RapidMiner user community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com/), you may get more RapidMiner-specific help as well.